# Trouble returning an array through Java Web Service

Tags: java, arrays, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to return an object which has few Strings as well an another array of Strings (there's a reason for this, I promise).  The trouble I'm having is that when I test my method with SoapUI, I only get the Strings; the array of Strings seems to be missing entirely.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong?  My class looks something like this...

```java
public class EmailListing {
  public String type;
  public String category;
  public String[] emails;

  public EmailListing() {
    emails = new String[1];
  }

  public void setEmailList(String emaillist) {
    this.emails = emaillist.split("\\|");
  }
}
```

In the web service function that uses this class, I do the following:

```java
public EmailListing getEmailListing(int id) {
  EmailListing el = new EmailListing();
  try {
    // get data from the database
    // ...
    //
    while(rs.next()) {
      el.type = rs.getString("type");
      el.category = rs.getString("category");
      el.setEmailList(rs.getString("emaillist"));
    }
  } catch(...) {
    ...
  }
  return el;
}
```

The only information I see when I test this service, though, is the type and category. :(

Edit: Method for printing and results of server-side output.

```java
public void print() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("Emails\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    sb.append("  " + emails[i] + "\n");
  }
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output looks like :

```
Emails
  XXXXX@gmail.com
  XXXXXXX@gmail.com
```

Edit: Adding recieved soap message

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getEmailListingResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com">
      <getEmailListingReturn>
        <type>data</type>
        <category>data</category>
      </getEmailListingReturn>
    </getEmailListingResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: your array of emails will never have more than one element in it. Look at the contructor for the EmailListing class. It would be extrmely helpful if you were to post an example of what is being returned. Does the function in the web service return and EmailListing?

Comment: I'll add the soap message I get back.

Comment: Your web service only returns an EmailListing that is not wrapped in anything else? Have any client code?

Comment: I am just testing it through SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

Debug it and see if you are actually getting the "emailList", if so you are probably splitting it wrong because your code looks good to me.

Comment: I print the contents of the object server side and the data is all there, just not when I ask for it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly does `EmailListing` look like? My best guess is that you'll need to create some sort of an [XmlTypeAdapter](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html).